# Access violation reading location When trying to get system time

Tags: c++

Here is the snippet of code where I try and get the time:

```
void GetDate(int &month,int &day,int &year){
  time_t SystemTime;

  struct tm *OSTime;
  OSTime=localtime(&SystemTime);

  month=OSTime->tm_mon;
  day=OSTime->tm_mday;
  year=OSTime->tm_year;

  month+=1;
  year+=1900;
}
```

When it gets to:

> month=OSTime->tm_mon;

it throws:

> Unhandled exception at 0x01101123 in GonzalesP2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000010.

Here is the method that calls GetDate:

```
void Calendar::SetMonthYear(int mon,string sYr){
  string temp;

  GetDate(tMonth,tDay,tYear);
  if(mon==0 && sYr=="0000"){
    mon=tMonth;
    sYr=tYear;
  }

  month=mon;
  //get the year
  temp=sYear.at(2);
  temp+=sYear.at(3);
  year=atoi(temp.c_str());
  //get the century
  temp=sYear.at(0);
  temp+=sYear.at(1);
  cent=atoi(temp.c_str());
  FillMonthGrid();
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one more step:

```
  time (&SystemTime); //^^Should first do this
  struct tm *OSTime;
  OSTime=localtime(&SystemTime);
```

You can find an example usage here: [localtime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime), call `time` before call `localtime`.

Comment: I don't have a var called time though and isn't that the same as `OSTime=localtime(&SystemTime);`

Comment: `time` is another function like `localtime`, not a variable. your `SystemTime` is not initialized, it is a simple an object of `time_t`. You need to first put current time into `SystemTime` by calling `time` function.

Comment: @jgonzales394 It is OK. The only thing matters is that it works.

Comment: @jgonzales394 You are welcome. You may consider accepting the answer when the system allows you to do it.